# ng-if not working on angular md table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angular-material

I am using angular md table [Angular md table](https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable) lib to display data in table.

I have to display data based on a condition in the cell, so I used `ng-if` but its not showing any thing in table column. I want to display different icon based on the value of `item.licReq`.

```
<mdt-table animate-sort-icon="true" ripple-effect="true" selectable-rows="false" table-card="{visible: true, title: 'License Screening', columnSelector: true}" paginated-rows="{isEnabled: true, rowsPerPageValues: [5,10,20,50]}">

    <mdt-header-row>

        <mdt-column align-rule="left" column-sort="true" column-definition="Screening Type"><span>Screening Type</span></mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="left" column-sort="true" column-definition="License Required"><span>License Required</span></mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="left" column-sort="true" column-definition="Status"><span>Status</span></mdt-column>

    </mdt-header-row>

    <mdt-row ng-repeat="item in licenseItems track by $index">       

        <mdt-cell><span>{{ item.screenType }}</span></mdt-cell>
        <mdt-cell><span>{{ item.licReq | liceReqFilter }}</span></mdt-cell>
        <mdt-cell><span> 
                        <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'N'">
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle green" uib-tooltip="License is not required." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'P'">
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle green" uib-tooltip="License provided." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>

                        <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'Y'">
                            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle red" uib-tooltip="License is required." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'E'">
                            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle red" uib-tooltip="License is expired." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>

                        <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'NA'">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" uib-tooltip="Invalid ECCN number." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
            </span>
        </mdt-cell>    
    </mdt-row>
</mdt-table>
```

If I use regular html table tag, ions are displayed properly. I have also tried angular `switch` directive.

**Working Code** :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="font-size: 12px">

    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #f9f9f9">
            <th>Sr</th>                                 
            <th>License Required</th>
            <th>Status</th>          
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>         
        <tr ng-repeat="item in licenseItems track by $index">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>                                 
            <td>{{item.licReq | liceReqFilter}}</td>
            <td>
                <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'N'">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle green" uib-tooltip="License is not required." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
                <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'P'">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle green" uib-tooltip="License provided." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>

                <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'Y'">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle red" uib-tooltip="License is required." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
                <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'E'">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle red" uib-tooltip="License is expired." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>

                <span ng-if="item.licReq == 'NA'">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" uib-tooltip="Invalid ECCN number." aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: Try changing it to ng-show

Comment: on changing `ng-if` to `ng-show` all the icons are displayed, like all the conditions in `ng-show` were evaluated to true.

Comment: @Vega this code works fine if i use html `table`, i can see the icons properly.

Comment: @Vega added working example with table tag

Comment: Could you shorten your code snippet to the revelent part, it's ward to go thru many lines up and down, or provide a plunker?

Comment: Removed some irrelevant columns.

Comment: it didnt worked in `mdt-custom-cell` also.

Comment: I am not sure, but have suspicion that that extra <span> may affect the layout. could you remove?

Comment: if i remove span it gives error : `angular.js:14362 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, i have to wrap all the columns in span to avoid this error.

Comment: Do you think you could setup a brief plunker?

Comment: created a link - [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/oOeEDd28xz5rKsdf9or3)

Comment: After testing with ng-show, ng-hide that don't work at all, as they weren't even there, I think we have bug here...